# how to print the selected pane inside FXML

Tags: java, javafx, printing, pane

i want to print the fxml contain pane but don't know how to do it. 
i try two code inside button action .

```
first

void doPrint(Node printPane) {
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
  if (job != null && job.showPageSetupDialog(printPane.getScene().getWindow())) {
                    job.printPage(printPane);
                    job.endJob();
                }
            }
        }


second

boolean doPrint(Node printPane) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!job.printPage(printPane)) {
            return false;
        }
        return job.endJob();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print any node you pass into it.

```
private void printImage(Node node) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("PRINTING FINISHED");
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on action event

```
@FXML
private void PrintAction(ActionEvent event) {


    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter(); //get the default printer
javafx.print.PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT); //create a pagelayout.  I used Paper.NA_LETTER for a standard 8.5 x 11 in page.
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();//create a printer job

if(job.showPrintDialog(tab_doctor_list.getScene().getWindow()))// this is very useful it allows you to save the file as a pdf instead using all of your printer's paper. A dialog box pops up, allowing you to change the "name" option from your default printer to Adobe pdf. 
{
    double pagePrintableWidth = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth(); //this should be 8.5 inches for this page layout.
    double pagePrintableHeight = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight();// this should be 11 inches for this page layout.


    tab_doctor_list.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.size(tab_doctor_list.getItems()).multiply(35));// If your cells' rows are variable size you add the .multiply and play with the input value until your output is close to what you want. If your cells' rows are the same height, I think you can use .multiply(1). This changes the height of your tableView to show all rows in the table.
    tab_doctor_list.minHeightProperty().bind(tab_doctor_list.prefHeightProperty());//You can probably play with this to see if it's really needed.  Comment it out to find out.
    tab_doctor_list.maxHeightProperty().bind(tab_doctor_list.prefHeightProperty());//You can probably play with this to see if it' really needed.  Comment it out to find out.

    double scaleX = pagePrintableWidth / tab_doctor_list.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();//scaling down so that the printing width fits within the paper's width bound.
    double scaleY = scaleX; //scaling the height using the same scale as the width. This allows the writing and the images to maintain their scale, or not look skewed.
    double localScale = scaleX; //not really needed since everything is scaled down at the same ratio. scaleX is used thoughout the program to scale the print out.

    double numberOfPages = Math.ceil((tab_doctor_list.getPrefHeight() * localScale) / pagePrintableHeight);//used to figure out the number of pages that will be printed.


}
```

}

Instead of **tab_doctor_list** use your **fx:id** of pane.